# GAPI Class, Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics-api

I am about to start a new project in the Google Analytics API & PHP.

I read that Google Analytics will be deprecating XML v2.3 and v2.4 and in 6 months time, so aparently you will only be able to use v3 and retrieve information in JSON format.

http://analytics.blogspot.com/2011/12/introducing-google-analytics-core.html

My question is the following: Does this means that GAPI class won't  work any longer? Anyone who has used this class before can help me answering this question ??

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/

In that case, any alternative suggestions of PHP classes that do the same thing.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I've been using GAPI for a while now. And I can say with some confidence that yes it will break, if not due to XML it will be due to some other change google makes.

Having said that GAPI is the best solution I have found out there for php. It does break every 6 months to a year, usually needs one or two lines changing to fix. But GAPI is pretty popular so at least you know when your clients are calling saying analytics is throwing errors at them, you wont be the only dev tearing your hair out.

9 times out of 10, by the time I've got a problem someone else has found the fix - which is nice.

There are a few other php options out there but GAPI seems to be the most popular (usually the best way to go imho)

My approach is to build an analytics summary in the dashboard and provide a link to google analytics underneath so clients can see the full data or go there when GAPI breaks. I have been putting all my sites on the same modular system for a while now. I keep GAPI as a library in my admin layout module, this means I can make the fix once and roll it out to all my sites without too much drama.

In summary, use it but expect it to break - that way you wont be disappointed when it does.